# Issues in executing Background Task in a UWP App

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-runtime, windows-10-universal, background-task

I am building a UWP application in Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2015 Version 14.0.25.425.01 Update 3 with Microsoft .NET Framework Version 4.6.01055. The current version of AWS .NET SDK I am using is v3.1.0.

I wish to perform a scheduled file upload task for which I created a time triggered background task project.

I added as reference the Windows Run-time Component (ScheduledUploadBackgroundTask) where I wrote the background task, in my App project (Storage File Explorer).
[Image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DLfwO.png)

I have also created a separate Class Library (AppUtils), where I have defined many utilities to be used in the upload background operation.This library is referenced in the background task WinRT.
[Image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Az5Al.png)

Now, I have a file path in my background task. When I do a *GetFileFromPathAsync(filePath)* I get the AccessDeniedException.
[Image3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g4tQh.png)

I am aware that WinRT has access to app's Local & Temp folders but the data (files/folders) I am uploading may be of very large volumes which leaves copying to Local/Temp folders not feasible.

Please suggest any workaround for this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I know, you cannot get files via the path (`C:\...`) directly in UWP. You would have to use Storage APIs to get files.

In your case, you would have to use [FileOpenPicker](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br207847) for the first time, then you could use [FutureAccessList](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.accesscache.storageapplicationpermissions.futureaccesslist.aspx) to store files and/or locations (like folders) and easily access these items in the future.

To see more code examples, please see the [File picker sample](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/File-picker-sample-9f294cba) and the [File access sample](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/File-access-sample-d723e597).

Comment: But i want to get the files in a Background Task (code in WRC) so I cannot use File/Folder Picker

Comment: @sanster23 For the first time, you have to use File/Folder Picker. Because you need to store files or locations into FutureAccessList. Then in the next use, you could get files via FutureAccessList directly.

Comment: is there a workaround to use Picker in a BackGroundTask without opening the picker on UI

Comment: @sanster23 The answer is No :)